# convert from string to int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have this code:

```
NSString * firstdDigitTest = [numberString substringToIndex:1];

        if (! [firstdDigitTest isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            numberString = [numberString substringFromIndex:1];
            self.firstImageName = [namefile stringByAppendingString:firstdDigitTest];

        }

        self.number = [numberString integerValue];
```

i check if the first number is not 0 and if it's not 0 i need to insert it to the `firstImageName`. But when i do it (using the `substringFromIndex`) and i try to use integerValue it's dosent work! 
without the `substringFromIndex` it's works! :(

Comment: I tested this, and it worked fine for me. Two questions. What do you get if you log numberString? And, What doesn't work? What results do you get? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *str0 = @"XXX10098";
NSString *str1 = [str0 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, str0.length-4)];
NSLog(@"%@", str1);

NSLog(@"%d", [str1 intValue]);


2012-10-28 10:52:07.309 iFoto[5652:907] 0098
2012-10-28 10:52:07.312 iFoto[5652:907] 98
```

Answer (score 0):

check `[numberString intValue];`

Comment: hmm. i think 0 is on 0 index, not 1.

Comment: In general, what you want to do? maybe it can be something better to do? Enter the details

Comment: no try that also.. the file name is: 10098 i need to retuen 0098

Comment: i get file name xxx10098.jpg and i have already the the xxx and now i need to get the number of images but is 98 and not 10098 so i try do take the 1 from the 10098 and insert it to xxx1 and get the rest 0098 and turn to int